# Getting only today's email with imap_search

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to grab all of my gmail emails based on today's current date using imap_search but I can't seem to get any results. I've made sure to set my timezone with date_default_timezone_set so I believe that's not the problem.

```
$mailConn = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $mailUser, $mailPass);
$search = 'ON ' . date('D, j M Y'); // search for today's email only
$emails = imap_search($mailConn, $search);
echo $search . '<br><br><br>'; // echoes ON Thu, 1 Jan 2015

if ($emails) {
    foreach ($emails as $emailID) {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($mailConn, $emailID, 0);
        echo $overview[0]->subject . ' - ' . $overview[0]->date . '<br><br><br>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No emails found.';
}
```

Does the date need to be exactly formatted based on $overview[0]->date in order for imap_search to find it? When I search for all emails and output $overview[0]->date this is what I get.

```
$mailConn = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $mailUser, $mailPass);
$search = 'ALL'; // search for all email
$emails = imap_search($mailConn, $search);
if ($emails) {
    foreach ($emails as $emailID) {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($mailConn, $emailID, 0);
        echo $overview[0]->date . '<br><br><br>'; // echoes Thu, 1 Jan 2015 13:52:23 -0500
    }
} else {
    echo 'No emails found.';
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php#109496

Answer (score 0):

A valid date for imap_search would be in the form of e.g. 22-Jul-2012